# Not able to access # param value of URL using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

In my page I have an ajax call for search and filtering and all the filter selection I am appending in URL as a `#` param (as appending in form of query string it will refresh the page).

By my problem is that I am not able to access this (`#` values) in my code behind (using c#).

I tried to store the `#` value in hidden field on `window.load` function of javascript, but I will not get this value in page load method of asp.net.

Can anybody suggest how to access this value on page load?

Comment: You need to provide some more information! May be some javascript and page code + some server code! 
What do you mean by "# value in hidden field on window.load function of javascript"?

Comment: In my page there is a Search button which triggers an ajax call, All the input field value as well all the selected filter value are taken an input parameter for ajax call.After the ajax response I am storing all this value on url like this : http://mysite/PR.aspx#l=20&text=Giyt&pg=20   This # values I need to access in my code behind

Comment: Did you try $(form).serialize()? [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: I am able to set the values in URL and also I am able to get the value using jquery but I am not able to find any way to access this value in aspx.cs file using c#

Answer (score 1):

Well, `#` is not sent to the server (it's not in the request), you can access it through javascript though, something like:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash !== "") {
    hash = hash.substring(1);
    alert(hash);
}
```

If you have to access it on the server, I'm affraid you have to place a query string:

```
http://yoururl/?test=123
```

Then you access with: `Request.QueryString["test"]` - will get you 123.

Comment: Thanks but how to access this value in the code behind file using c#.

Comment: I want to find the way to access this value using c#

Comment: I tried to set this hash value in hidden field using jQuery, but on Page_Load method I wont be able to get this value.

Comment: As this values I am setting during the ajax call and if I set in the form of proper query string then it will reload the page and will kill purpose of using ajax.

Comment: @user1803513 I don't see how that's an issue ? Ajax -> send the value to the server -> do stuff there -> get results ? No reload, really.

Comment: Yes after the ajax I need to store all the input parameter somewhere so that if somebody bookmark this link or copied this url then he should be able to see the same filtered result